# filter datatable by date and number

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, api

hey i want to filter my table i have two options filter by date and filter by number when i filter by date its work fine and also when i delete filter by date script and try to filter by cheque number it will work perfectly but the problem is that it does not work when i use both scripts means at that time it filter by date but not by cheque number...its giving me error cheque date is not null but if i set any cheque date and then filter by number than it will filter only the selected date in between result not search entire table.

alert:DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //use a special class name or id for the table
    //using find I'm getting all tr elements in the table
    //using not(':eq(0)') I'm ignoring the first tr element
    //using each I'm iterating through the selected elements
    $('table').find('tr').not(':eq(0)').each(function(i){
        //using children('td:eq(0)') I'm getting the first td element inside the tr
        $(this).children('td:eq(0)').addClass('sno').text(i+1);
  
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#divChqDate").hide();
 $("#divCheque").hide();
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
        
    });
  /* Initialise datatables */
  var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable();

  $("#sea").click(function() {
    //Creating of our own filtering function
    $.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push(
        function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
        var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
        var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
           var Chequeno = parseInt(aData[2]);
           
        if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( isNaN( min ) && Chequeno >= max ) ||
             ( min <= Chequeno   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( min <=Chequeno    && Chequeno <= max ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);

    //Update table
     oTable.fnDraw();
     //Deleting the filtering function if we need the original table later.

  });

});
</script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#divChqDate").hide();
 $("#divCheque").hide();
 var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
        
    });
 $("#from").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true ,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
            $("#to").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var from = $('#from').datepicker("getDate");
            var to = $('#to').datepicker("getDate");
   //alert(from.getTime())
   //alert(to.getTime())
            var startDate = new Date(data[3]);
    if ((from.getTime() == null && to.getTime() == null) ||
     (from.getTime() == null && startDate.getTime() <= to.getTime()) ||
     (to.getTime() == null && startDate.getTime() >= from.getTime()) ||
     (startDate.getTime() <= to.getTime() && startDate.getTime() >= from.getTime()) )
   {
    return true; 
   }
            return false;
        }
        );
  table.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        table.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();
       // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
            $('#from, #to').change(function () {
             oTable.fnDraw();
            });
        });
       



function getval(sel)
{
 if (sel.value == 1)
 {
 $("#divChqDate").show();
 $("#divCheque").hide();
 
 //reloadTable();
 }
 else if(sel.value == 2)
 {
 $("#divChqDate").hide();
 $("#divCheque").show();
 }
    //alert(sel.value);
}
</script>
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
<form action="/cheque/report/" name="report">
Search By :<select id="topay" onchange="getval(this);">
   <option value="0">Select Option</option>
   <option value="1">Cheque Date</option>
   <option value="2">Cheque No.</option>
</select>
<div id="divChqDate">
<b><p>Cheque Date:</p>
From: <input id="from" autocomplete="off"/>
To: <input id="to" autocomplete="off"/>
<button type="button" onclick="location.reload();">Refresh</button>
<button onclick="printDiv();">Print it</button></b>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="divCheque">
<b><p>Cheque No: </p> 
From: <input id="min"  name="min"  autocomplete="off" maxlength="6" />
To: <input id="max"  name="max"  autocomplete="off" maxlength="6" />
<button type="button" id="sea">Search</button></b>
</div>
<div id="print-content">
<b><u><h2 align="center">Details of Cheque</h2></b></u>
<table id="datatable" name="table" class="display" >
<thead>
  <tr>
 <th>S.No</th>
    <th>To_Pay   </th>
    <th> Cheque_No </th>
    <th>Cheque_Date</th>
    <th>Entry_Date</th>
 <th> Remarks </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody> 
 {% for report in reports %}
  <tr>
    <td class="sno"></td>
 <td>{{report.topay}}</td>
    <td>{{report.chequeno}}</td>
    <td>{{report.chequedate | date:"Y-m-d"}}</td>
    <td>{{report.date | date:"Y-m-d"}}</td>
 <td>{{report.remarks}}</td>
 
  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
  <tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You could try to use django filters within your views

Comment: is this not possible by jquery?? @JuanIgnacioSánchez

Comment: Sure, but you should avoid this kind of business logic on client side. Even more using such powerful framework as django

Comment: can u share some doc related thisproblem

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/ this is for version 1.11 which is lts, but you can change it once you are into the web.

Comment: cant understand these doc... its confusing

Comment: looking like very tough explenation